# VUE JS cannot auto run time counterdown

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

This is my vuejs file

```
<v-col md="6">
  <p class="title text-center">Timer: {{count}}s</p>
</v-col>
export default { 
  data () {
   return {
     count: null
   }
  },
  created () {
    this.count
  },
  computed: {
   downCount () {
     this.count = this.$store.getters.countingDown
   }
  },
}
```

I cannot auto run, but when I click tab vue on inspect element it's work

Comment: What's the code of your ```countingDown``` getter in your store.js file?

Comment: `Computed` function are not supposed to produce `side effect` but only return values

Comment: Remove the `count` data property and change your computed property to `count () { return this.$store.getters.countingDown }`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a computed property `count` as shown below:

```
 <v-col md="6">
      <p class="title text-center">Timer: {{count}}s</p>
    </v-col>
    export default { 
      data () {
       return {
         count: null
       }
      },
      created () {
        this.count
      },
      computed: {
       count() {
         return this.$store.getters.countingDown
       }
      },
    }
```

Hope this helps.